# Entity Framework - Qual é a diferença entre Com EntityState.Modified e Sem EntityState.Modified?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Qual é a diferença entre os dois ?

**Com EntityState:**

```
var registro = db.MinhaTabela.Where(a => a.MeuCampo == "Valor_Antigo").FirstOrDefault();
registro.MeuCampo = "Valor_Novo";
db.Entry(registro).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Sem EntityState:**

```
var registro = db.MinhaTabela.Where(a => a.MeuCampo == "Valor_Antigo").FirstOrDefault();
registro.MeuCampo = "Valor_Novo";
db.SaveChanges();
```

Parece que os dois funcionam mesma coisa ou é diferente ?

Comment: Entry é para objetos que não estão no contexto, o seu primeiro exemplo não é usado, porque, não é preciso que seja assim, o segundo é porque o objeto está no contexto e todas as alterações podem ser confirmadas com `SaveChanges`. Um exemplo é em MVC quando o objeto é para alteração e o mesmo não está no contexto, precisa então utilizar o Entry e dizer que ele é uma alteração.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, obrigado pelo seu comentário. Me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `State` informa ao Entity Framework o estado do seu objeto. No seu primeiro exemplo, não é necessário setar o `State`: o próprio Entity Framework fará isso pra você.

Mas no caso de estar "desconectado" do banco, ou seja, criar um objeto fora do contexto, como @virgilionovic mencionou no comentário, você pode usar o `State` para informar o que o Entity Framework fará com o objeto ao tentar salvá-lo.

De qualquer forma, isso tem um inconveniente: todos os atributos serão alterados. No segundo exemplo, o Entity Framework fez o *tracking* do seu objeto, e sabe que somente precisa atualizar "MeuCampo", enquanto que no primeiro, todos os campos serão atualizados, ainda que não tenham sido alterados. Além de alterar campos desnecessários, pode ter outras consequências, caso por exemplo seu banco tenha *constraints* em alguns dos campos que serão validados, tornando o processo de update mais lento.

Comment: Apenas uma correção: não sei de que versão você está falando, mas na versão 6 do Entity Framework este comportamento de "atualizar tudo" não é bem assim. O *framework* é espertinho pra saber quais campos foram modificados em ambos os casos. No mais, quando a entidade está destacada do contexto, sim, é isso mesmo: ao informar o `EntityState`, o contexto verifica a entidade e passa a observá-la.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez é verdade, bem apontado. Temos também que lembrar da propriedade `AutoDetectChangesEnabled`, que se setada para false pode mudar a forma como o Entity Framework detecta as alterações.